# Unable to Install JDK 1.8 64-bit on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, 64-bit, java, jdk

I have installed `Windows 10 64 bit` on my system, Now when i am trying to install `JDK 1.8 64-bit`, its giving me following error message.

[image]

These are my system configurations

[image]

I have successfully install `32-bit JDK`, but its creating problems with `Android Studio`, so i need to install `JDK 64Bit`.

Kindly guide me.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly which JDK 1.8 64-bit installer did you try?

Comment: This is name of the file i downloaded. `jdk-8u91-windows-x64.exe`

Comment: "I just spent 90 minutes on the phone with Microsoft to sort this problem out, and they finally decided that the latest versions (past v51) of Java doen't play well with the WMI installer if the Windows 10 machine was upgraded from Win7.. They were able to get version 51 (old) installed, but nothing more recent, and they basically said that I was out of luck until Java fixes the problem, or until I buy Windows10 and do a clean windows install."...https://community.oracle.com/thread/3825840?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks @Moab, So Would it work fine, if i install JDK 1.7.

Comment: I have no clue, that was just something I found using google.

Comment: I have no idea whom, the person talked to, who claims Microsoft said that but it wasn't Microsoft.  I can confirm that the current version and past versions of Java installer run without an issue on Windows 10.  Considering Windows is literally installed over Windows 7, it makes no sense that doing an upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 would have a effect on anything.  if you choose to keep your files, those files are moved to another part of the disk, the moved back.  There is from a low level function no difference between a Clean Install and an Upgrade install at least with Windows 10.

Comment: Are you able to open it with a uncompressing utility (ie 7zip, winzip, etc) You would also try [Convert jdk to zip](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1619662/3228766)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the icon in your screenshot:

[image: Bad JDK Icon]

It looks like the file you downloaded is corrupted, or just not completed.

Once downloaded the icon should appear as the Java logo, and the file size should be ~187MB.

[image: Good JDK Icon]

Try downloading the file again (PS: [jdk-*8u92*-windows-x64.exe](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) exists now).

Comment: Thanks, I am downloading it again. I will update, if it works.